# How to make input valid with js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, required

I have a required input :

```
<input type="text" id="input-id" required>
```

When user submit it I send its value with ajax and then clear it with
 `$("#input-id").val("")`. 
After it input becomes invalid, but I want to make it looks like it did right after page loading. How can I do it with js? Maybe I should clear input in another way?

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood what you wanted. What value did the input text have before the ajax, and what does it have afterwards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do what's written [here](https://www.formget.com/reset-form-fields-using-javascript/):

```
document.getElementById(selector).reset();
```

if you want to reset a particular field, try use `defaultValue`:

```js
function reset() {
  field = document.getElementById('field');
  field.value = field.defaultValue;
}
```

```html
<input id="field" type="text" required>
<button onclick="reset()">reset field</button>
```

Another solution will be to define a **form within a form**, that contains only the fields you want to reset, and then reset the inner form.

Comment: It only works with forms whereas I want to apply it to input

Comment: @DeadUnicorn you are right, I edited the answer, check if it's working for you

Comment: It has the same effect as $(selector).val(""). Field becomes invalid after it

Comment: @DeadUnicorn read about the form within a form solution I suggested

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#input-id").val("");
   //If you also want to set innerText:
   var ele = document.getElementById('input-id');
   ele.innerText= $("#input-id").val();
};
```

As soon as the document is ready (the page is loaded) then the input becomes invalid. Place this wherever you think is appropriate.

Comment: The problem is to make it valid after `$("#input-id").val("")` (without putting text inside of it)

Comment: @DeadUnicorn Just to clarify, did you care only about val() or also about innerText?

Comment: @DeadUnicorn added an innerText thing too if that's what you wanted?